# pandas groupby and then select a row by value of column (min,max, for example)

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
Category Data1 column1
A 'SOMEDATA' 10
A 'SOMEDATA' 2
A 'SOMEDATA' -10
B 'SOMEDATA' 10
B 'SOMEDATA' 1
B 'SOMEDATA' -10
```

and so on

I'd like to select a one row in each group by column value.  For example, ABS(column1)

So resulting data is

```
Category Data1 column1
A 'SOMEDATA' 2
B 'SOMEDATA'  1
```

How can I do this in python?

I couldn't figure out how to return entire row.  For example,

```
df.groupby('Category')['column1'].min();
```

this would only return 'Category' min(column1)  only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and (2) Why is voting important? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.  -- Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that is more computationally efficient.

**TL;DR version**

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Category')['column1'].idxmin()]
```

Answer (score 2):

`sort` then `.drop_duplicates`, if you want single minimum row based on absolute value.

```
(df.assign(to_sort = df.column1.abs()).sort_values('to_sort')
     .drop_duplicates('Category').drop(columns='to_sort'))

  Category       Data1  column1
4        B  'SOMEDATA'        1
1        A  'SOMEDATA'        2
```

Sort can only sort on existing columns, so we need to create the column of absolute values (with `.assign`). Sorting then ensures the minumum absolute value appears first, and dropping duplicates keeps the first row for each category, which is now the minumum absolute value row.

Also possible with `groupby`, which is better if you need to return more than one row per group:

```
df.assign(to_sort = df.column1.abs()).sort_values('to_sort').groupby(df.Category).head(1)
```

---

Alternatively, you can slice with the result of a `groupby`. This is useful in cases where you want to return **all** rows that match the minimum:

```
df[df.groupby(df.Category, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.column1 == x.column1.abs().min())]

  Category       Data1  column1
1        A  'SOMEDATA'        2
4        B  'SOMEDATA'        1
```